# How to use Keras Lambda layer to merge 2 dimensions and Transpose

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I have a vector of shape (1,9,128). I need it converted to (128,9), but not with a simple reshape. I want the 1 and 9 to merge and then a transpose. How can I do this with the Lambda layer in keras? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```
def reshapeTranspose(x):

    x = K.reshape(x,(9,128))
    return K.permute_dimensions(x,(1,0))
```

The layer:

```
Lambda(reshapeTranspose, output_shape=(128,9))
```

PS: `output_shape` is not necessary if you're using tensorflow.
PS2: Beware of the batch size, usually it's the first dimension in keras tensors that you haven't created yourself.